# How much Disk I/O Speed do I need in ratio to Disk I/O demand

Tags: io, cpu-usage, vps, digital-ocean, system-administration

My Digital Ocean VPS hits a max of 8 MB/sec of disk activity.

When I do a test loading a 512MB file, my server writes an average of 350 MB/sec, does this mean that performance won't suffer until Disk IO demand reaches 350 MB/sec? Or will performance slowly suffers until everything stops working at 350 MB/sec.

What would you guys recommend in terms of max-demand/average-ability ratio. So let's say that a server gets 100 MB/sec max at peak time, what server disk speed would you use in that case.

Sorry if this was worded poorly. I'm new to this. Will reword if clarification needed.

Comment: What kind of disk(s)?  When you get 350MB/sec to your disk, how are you writing it?  Are you writing large blocks sequentially, or small blocks randomly?

Comment: For my test I just averaged the results of this command:

"dd bs=1M count=512 if=/dev/zero of=test conv=fdatasync"

In real life I never reach 350 MB/sec. Max out at 8ish. It is an SSD on DigitalOcean. 8GB Droplet

Comment: Streaming large-block IO like that isn't going to test how well a disk handles random IO.  Spinning disks can handle about 50 to 200+ random IO operations per second, with consumer-grade disks (5400 and 7200 RPM SATA) usually around 50-70 operations/second.  If each operation is a 4kB disk block, IO rates will be under 300kB/sec.  And if the IO operation is smaller than that, IO rates will be even lower, possibly into a few kB/sec.  Actual, physical IO patterns make a huge difference in the IO rate a spinning disk can support.